# What is the significance of a diagonal input in a control diagram?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, systems-design

I have seen several block diagrams with diagonal inputs, drawn with an arrow through the block.

[image] [and others like that (via Google image search)](https://www.google.com/search?q=indirect+adaptive+control&biw=1550&bih=720&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=CYYIVbfkFImegwT41oHwCA&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#imgdii=_&imgrc=gULVia1RSqWyPM%253A%3BgD-PX1e3g17aiM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fieeexplore.ieee.org%252Fiel5%252F5%252F20157%252F931488%252F1104583.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fieeexplore.ieee.org%252Fiel5%252F5%252F20157%252F931488%252F931488.plain.html%3B444%3B246)

What is difference between this and a typical signal input? What are the dotted lines signifying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diagonal input generally means that it changes some parameter of the block, such as its gain, without otherwise becoming part of the signal that the block is processing.